# Choose the right hardware to build a squid proxy server (200 users)

Tags: hardware, squid, sizing

I need to prepare a squid proxy server for my company.
We have a new fiber connection (100 mbit) and I need to give access with user and pass, speed up navigation with caching and do a little web filtering.
The only thing that I would really care about is correctly sizing the proxy's hardware because I do not want it to be our new connection's bottleneck.

I'd prefer to spend the lowest possible but I'd appreciate hints about what I really should get:

Ram?
Cpu?
Fast disk?
Gigabit ethernet?

Thanks to anybody who'll help.

Comment: Are you sure you need a squid server with a 100 mbit connection?  proxy hits are pretty minimal and your connection is so fast anyway.  I would just pursue the web filtering route if that is needed.  Not much hardware is needed there.

Comment: So I'd just need authentication and web filtering...
What kind of hardware would be good, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This document may give you some ideas/pointers/references](http://ws.edu.isoc.org/data/2006/1156601184448218a95833f/squidhardwarecofiguration.htm)